# Pro-p completion of a quotient of $U/w(U)$ is virtually nilpotent for a finitely generated free group $U$

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, completion

Let $w$ be a word of a free group. Assume that $H/\overline{w(H)}$ is virtually nilpotent for every finitely generated pro-$p$ group $H$. Let $U$ be a finitely generated free group and $T$ the maximal residually nilpotent quotient of $U/w(U)$.

> If $\widehat{T_p}$ is the pro-$p$ completion of $T$, how can I show that $\widehat{T_p}$ is virtually nilpotent?

My attempts was to try to show that $\widehat{T_p}$ is isomorphic to $\widehat{U_p}/\overline{w(\widehat{U_p})}$ or something like that but I could not conclude it. I'm not looking for a proof, I just would like to know if this way works (and so, some guidance) or if there is a better approach. Thanks in the advance!

---

This claim [theorem 5.2] is from the paper "On the verbal width of finitely generated pro-p groups" by Andrei Jaikin-Zapirain ([link at ProjectEuclid](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmi/1218475356)).

Comment: What is $w(H)$? Why is it a subgroup?

Comment: @dodd is the verbal subgroup of $H$. By definition $w(H)$ is generated by $H_w$ where $H_w$ is the set of all $w$-values in $H$.

Comment: Jaikin-Zapirain answers emails as far as I know.